# How to ensure finish of main thread last

Tags: java, multithreading

I examine Java multythreading programming. My task is to implement a multi-threaded program to compute the matrix product. Each thread is responsible for a different line of the resulting matrix. The task says: "Use `join()` in the main program to wait all threads to finish before printing out the resulting matrix".

So here is my code:

**MatrixProduct.java**

```
package multythreading;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MatrixProduct {

    public static Matrix a;
    public static Matrix b;

    static {
        a = new Matrix(new int[][]{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
                                   {4, 5, 64, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11},
                                   {7, 8, 94, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12},
                                   {7, 8, 94, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13},
                                   {4, 5, 64, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14},
        });
        b = new Matrix(new int[][]{{2, 1, 3},
                                   {4, 2, 1},
                                   {6, 4, 5},
                                   {6, 4, 5},
                                   {4, 2, 1},
                                   {2, 1, 3},
                                   {4, 2, 1},
                                   {6, 4, 5},
                                   {6, 4, 5},
                                   {4, 2, 1}});
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[a.getRowNum()];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new ResultMatrixLine(i), "Line number " + i + " computation thread");
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (Thread t: threads) {
            if (t.isAlive()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(t.getName() + " : " + t.getState()  + " still alive");
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All computation threads terminated and the resulting matrix is ready");
    }
}

class ResultMatrixLine implements Runnable {

    private int lineNumber;

    public ResultMatrixLine(int lineNumber) {
        this.lineNumber  = lineNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Line number = " + lineNumber + ": " + Arrays.toString(getResultLine()));
    }

    private int[] getResultLine() {
        int[] result = new int[MatrixProduct.b.getColumnNum()];
        for (int i = 0; i < MatrixProduct.b.getColumnNum(); i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < MatrixProduct.a.getColumnNum(); j++)
                result[i] += MatrixProduct.a.getMatrixElement(lineNumber, j)*MatrixProduct.b.getMatrixElement(j, i);
        return result;
    }
}

class Matrix {
    private final int columnNum;
    private final int rowNum;
    private final int[][] matrix;

    public Matrix(int[][] matrix) {
        this.columnNum = matrix[0].length;
        this.rowNum = matrix.length;
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    public int getColumnNum() {
        return columnNum;
    }

    public int getRowNum() {
        return rowNum;
    }

    public int getMatrixElement(int columnIndx, int rowIndx) {
        return matrix[columnIndx][rowIndx];
    }
}
```

Resulting matrix's lines are calculated independently, so the only thing I care about is using `join()` in `main()` method properly. I mean at the end of the main thread all other threads must be terminated so that the resulting matrix is ready. My decision works fine at the first glance but I'd like to see any comments on it.

Comment: I think this is a better fit for codereview...

Comment: `t.join()` does exactly what you appear to expect it to do:  It waits for thread `t` to terminate.

Comment: You should look at the java streams API. This API doesn't have you create `Thread`s yourself. On a side note: You should definitely read about multithreading in general and how to do it and how to not do it (namely: spawn a new Thread for every small Task - such as computing a single row of a matrix product). Useful helpers around multithreading that save you from having to do Thead management yourself are a good starter. For Java these are `java.future` and the new parallel Stream API.

Comment: Using join() makes the threads run in order right? Not all at once?

Comment: I've only briefly skimmed over your question but as an alternate to stream API, I suggest reading up on [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and see if you can make use of it. The invokeAll might be what you're looking for. (and don't forget to shutdown at the end!)

Comment: @Dominic No. It makes the *calling* thread wait until the *called* thread finishes. If you started all threads at the same time, they run concurrently. If you then call `join`, the calling thread waits for the called thread to finish, but the other threads run concurrently in the background.

Comment: @Polygnome thank you for the clarification!  That's actually some pretty useful information I would have used.  Not even my university professor mentioned that when we went over Threads!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution I created from modifying your code:

Added an ArrayList to the *Matrix Product* and a function to remove a thread from it in a public scope:

```
private static ArrayList<ResultMatrixLine> threads = new ArrayList<>();


public static void main(String [] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.getRowNum(); i++) {
        // Create a new ResultMatrixLine thread
        ResultMatrixLine thread = new ResultMatrixLine( i );
        // Keep the thread handy for manipulation later
        threads.add( thread );
        // Create a new thread
        thread.start();
    }

    threads.stream().forEach( (thread) -> {
        if( thread.isAlive() ) {
            try {
                thread.join( 1000 );
            } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
                ex.printStackTrace( System.out );
            }
        }
    });

    System.out.println("All computation threads terminated and the resulting matrix is ready");

}
```

**Output**

```
Line number = 1: [670, 423, 503]
Line number = 3: [876, 556, 667]
Line number = 0: [254, 151, 165]
Line number = 4: [682, 429, 506]
Line number = 2: [872, 554, 666]
All computation threads terminated and the resulting matrix is ready
```

Using the join() method for threads, after creating all of the threads it will then loop through the ArrayList and check if any of the threads are alive.  If so, join() them.

Comment: Don't dump code, explain every change you made and *why* you made it.

Comment: @Polygnome is that better for you?

Comment: Its not about whats better for me, its what is better for future readers with a similar problem. SO aims at building a knowledge base, after all. Commenting code is a start, but its not the same as actually explaining how stuff works. Besides I don't see how your answer works at all. `thread.run()` calls the runnables `run` method, it doesn't actually start the thread, so the work isn't done concurrently, which is obviously what the OP wants.

Comment: @Polygnome you're correct in saying that. That is my bad.  I notice the defects of my above code.  Fixing...